# unable to select image from remote database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I m accessing remote database through `DBLINK`, but when trying to fire select query to fetch image stored in BLOB datatype it gives me following error:

```
ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to handle LOBs in Oracle dblink'ed tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074/best-way-to-handle-lobs-in-oracle-dblinked-tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide the statement you are trying to execute, but I guess you are trying to do something which simply isn't possible in Oracle 10g.

The docs at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref161 state:

> Oracle Database has limited support for remote LOBs. Remote LOBs are
>   supported in three ways.
>
> 1. Create table as select or insert as select.
> 2. Functions on remote LOBs returning scalars. SQL and PL/SQL functions having a LOB parameter and returning a scalar datatype are
>      supported. Other SQL functions and DBMS_LOB APIs are not supported for
>      use with remote LOB columns.
> 3. Data Interface for remote LOBs. You can insert a character or binary buffer into a remote CLOB or BLOB, and select a remote CLOB or
>      BLOB into a character or binary buffer.
>
> These are the only supported syntax involving LOBs in remote tables.
>   No other usage is supported.

See the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref161) for extended examples.

Comment: There seems to be a [partial workaround](http://technology.amis.nl/2012/07/02/select-a-blob-across-a-database-link-without-getting-ora-22992/) for this; but as [Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:696224943687#5143032900346117375) notes it may be something that stops working in the future, so shouldn't be relied upon.

Answer (score 1):

To access data of type `BLOB` use the `PIC` datatype. Build your query like this:

```
*select(
  **select PIC from  AGENT_SIGNATURES_TB@DBLINK**
)  as PIC
from dual*
```

At least that worked for me on an Oracle database.